# Por que recebo a declaração: "indice.push is not s function"?

Tags: javascript

*Criei um código simples de javascript que adiciona o índice dos maiores valores à uma lista, entretanto não entendo por que não consigo usar a função .push() neste código:*

**Observe a linha 12**

```
1    var list=[1,7,8,9,3,6,9];
2    var contador=0;
3    var primeiro=list[0];
4    var indice=[];
5    function maior(){
6        while (contador<list.length){
7            if (primeiro<list[contador]){
8                primeiro=list[contador];
9                indice=list[contador];
10           }
11           else if (primeiro==list[contador]){
12               indice.push(contador);
13           }
14           contador=contador+1;
15           console.log("indice: #"+contador+" numero:"+list[contador-1]);
16       }
17       console.log("O maior número é: "+primeiro);
18       console.log("Os maiores numeros estão na posição: "+indice);
19   }  
20   console.log("A lista tem: "+list.length+" números");
21   maior();
```

*Eu sei outras formas de escrevê-lo e resolver o problema, mas quero entender o porquê de receber a mensagem de que a função .push() não pode ser usada, para que eu possa aprimorar meu conhecimento. Quaisquer outras dicas também serão bem vindas.*

Comment: O que a linha 9 faz?

Comment: Se o número de comparação *(primeiro)*, for o maior, ele adiciona o índice desse número à lista; entretanto eu a transformei em outra variável ao invés de adicionar esse número à lista, perdendo assim a função de lista e o método .push!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta atribuindo a variável `indice` na linha 9 um valor inteiro, você tem que adicionar o valor com push na linha 9 também.

Comment: Exatamente! Eu sou uma besta XD

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Relaxa! Acontece nas melhores famílias.